# How to retrieve and separate multiple data passed in an array from One Activity to another via Intent

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity, expandablelistview

I am unable to separate two data elements passed together via an array in the receiving Activity

I have passed material data and Price data via the same Intent Extra to another activity. I have successfully received the data in the recieving Activity and published to a Textview field. such that it looks like this, "Chicken wings 1000" on the screen. However I want to separate both pieces of data to two different Textview fields on the same screen. the issue is I am unable to separate both from the Array. My code is below

In the sending Activity

```
Cursor category1 = controller.categotyforGroupedLv();
        Cursor itemListCategory;
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listHash = new HashMap<>();

        if (category1.getCount() == 0) {
           category1.moveToFirst();

        }

                 while (category1.moveToNext()) {
                listDataHeader.add(" " + category1.getString(1));


                itemListCategory = controller.getFPMsster(category1.getString(1));   

                List<String> listDataItem = new ArrayList<>();
                if (itemListCategory.getCount() != 0) {
                    while(itemListCategory.moveToNext()) {
                        listDataItem.add(" " + itemListCategory.getString(3)+ " " + itemListCategory.getString(4));
```

The Intent is

```
 mIntent = new Intent(OrderTakingScreen.this,
                        OrderTakingScreen2_OrderDetails.class);

                               mIntent.putExtra("keyName", listHash.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition));
```

In the receiving Activity I have

```
 TextView menuChoice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuchoice);
    String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
    menuChoice.setText(data);
```

In the "KeyName" variable I have "Chicken Wings 1000" printed to the TextView field. I want to be able to separate them and have "Chicken Wings" printed to one TextView Screen and "1000" printed to a different TextView field

Comment: How do you get data? Do you get it separately or all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the pattern of each string: 
meaning that the last piece of data is a number or a single word 
then they can be separated by finding the index of the last space char:

```
String text = "Chicken wings 1000";
String item1 = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(' '));
String item2 = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
System.out.println("item1 = " + item1);
System.out.println("item2 = " + item2);
```

will print

```
item1 = Chicken wings
item2 = 1000
```

Comment: thank you @forpas.. worked like a charm. cannot believe it was that easy, been battling this for two days now. Much appreciated